# STL decomposition - independence of components

Tags: r, time-series, independence, variance-decomposition

Let's suppose we have 3 vectors $U_1$, $U_2$ and $U_3$ we construct another vector $V=U_1+U_2+U_3$.

If $X$, $Y$ and $Z$ and independent, [we can expect](http://www.stat.yale.edu/Courses/1997-98/101/rvmnvar.htm) that $VAR(V)=\sum_{i=1}^3 VAR(U_i)$, right?

Now let's look at a more practical example involving time series. We can decompose time series into trend, seasonality and error using [STL](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/stl.html), so in this case, we can say that the variables $U_i$, are the components extracted via STL decomposition and the $V$ variable represents the original series.

Consider the following example in R:

```
set.seed(123)
x <- ts(rnorm(144, sd=1), frequency=12)
a <- stl(x, s.window="periodic")
sum(apply(a$time.series, 2, var) / var(x))
# [1] 0.9621605
```

Can we then conclude that the components (trend, seasonality and errors) are not independent? If so, then why?

In the above example, the value is pretty close to 1, but I have seen instances where this value is approximately 0.7, but I'm afraid I cannot share this data.

Comment: They aren't independent because they are constrained to sum to the original series; that's basically what allows you to calculate the errors.